How can one route VM traffic through another external IP?
I have a server with two IP addresses attached to a single interface:
2: enp27s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:9c:23:83:64:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet [IP_1]/32 scope global noprefixroute enp27s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet [IP_2]/32 scope global enp27s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 [IP6_1]/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

And I have a few virtual machines running on it and whenever they communicate with the outside world, their packets get IP_1 as the source IP. I also have a specific VM which I'd like to "route" through IP_2 instead. I don't want to attach it entirely to that IP address, I'd still prefer for it to stay inside the virtual network, but I want all of the packets coming out of it have IP_2 as their source IP.
I tried to apply a SNAT translation to achieve that, but it didn't really work:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s [VM_IP] -o enp27s0 -j SNAT --to-source [IP_2]

I assume that's because by the time packets finish routing they already have IP_1 as source IP and the -s [VM_IP] part of rule doesn't match. Changing that to -s [IP_1] or just setting IP_2 as the primary IP could work probably, but I kinda need other VMs to have their outgoing traffic be routed through IP_1.
Are there any ways to achieve that? I'm pretty sure a question like that has been asked here before, but unfortunately my inexperience prevents me from coming up with keywords to put in the search bar to find it :(

Update: here's my POSTROUTING table rules (excluding that one SNAT rule):
# iptables -t nat -S POSTROUTING
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT

# iptables -t nat -S LIBVIRT_PRT
-N LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE


Order matters in your netfilter rules. Can you show us the other rules in your POSTROUTING table (iptables -t nat -S POSTROUTING)?

@larsks sure thing, i've added the list to the question, although there aren't many rules in there

Sorry, you'll need to follow that -j LIBVIRT_PRT. Either add iptables -t nat -S LIBVIRT_PRT, or just include everything (iptables -t nat -S).

Given your existing ruleset, when you run...
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s [VM_IP] -o enp27s0 -j SNAT --to-source [IP_2]

...it gets appended at the end of the POSTROUTING chain, so you end up with:
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A POSTROUTING -s [VM_IP] -o enp27s0 -j SNAT --to-source [IP_2]

That's too late; at this point, the packet has already traversed the MASQUERADE rules and will no longer match -s [VM_IP]. This rule will probably do what you want if you move it in front of the -J LIBVIRT_PRT rule:
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s [VM_IP] -o enp27s0 -j SNAT --to-source [IP_2]

Using -I (without an explicit index) inserts the rule at the top of the chain.

Oh, I see. It works now, thanks.
